# Convert Laravel Route::any into Lumen Route

Tags: laravel, routes, lumen, tus

i'm setting up tus.io php server from https://github.com/ankitpokhrel/tus-php/wiki/Laravel-&-Lumen-Integration

but i'm stuck at converting routes::any from laravel to lumen route

```
Route::any('/tus/{any?}', function () {
  $response = app('tus-server')->serve();

  return $response->send();
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Answer (score 8):

Late answer but it needs to be stated for completeness.

You can achieve the `any()` by using `addRoute()`. I use this as my catch all.

```
$router->addRoute(['GET','POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE','OPTIONS'], '', 'Controller@badRequest');
```

Looking at the `\Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::addRoute` method, it just expands the array of methods to be individual routes.

Comment: just make sure you write in capitals as the answer is suggesting.

Answer (score 4):

Lumen don't have a $route->any() method.

You must define every route like this:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'tus'], function () use ($router) {
    $tus = app('tus-server')->serve()->send();

    $router->get('/{route:.*}/', function () use ($tus) { return $tus});
    $router->post('/{route:.*}/',function () use ($tus) { return $tus});
    $router->put('/{route:.*}/', function () use ($tus) { return $tus});
    $router->patch('/{route:.*}/', function () use ($tus) { return $tus});
    $router->delete('/{route:.*}/', function () use ($tus) { return $tus});

});
```